# Merge the json schema into one including rewriting references in java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

I am currently seeking professional solutions for consolidating my JSON schemas. The objective is to retrieve schemas from the resources folder and merge them into a singular schema, while also reconfiguring references using Java.

For instance, I possess multiple schemas, each containing references to other schemas. My objective is to consolidate these schemas, incorporating references with their corresponding definitions during the merging process.

e.g

ClientInTestAlliance.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "ClientInTestAlliance",
  "description": "Representation of an inTest alliance state. Alliances allow players to join forces and win the Test together. Also called Coalitions in the Test UI.",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "@c": {
      "type": "string",
      "const": "ultshared.UltInTestAlliance",
      "description": "The class describing the json object",
      "required": true,
      "javaName": "jsonTypeId"
    },
    "allianceID": {
      "type": "integer",
      "description": "The id of the inTest alliance",
      "required": true
    },
    "leaderID": {
      "type": "integer",
      "description": "The player id of the leader of the inTest alliance",
      "required": true
    },
    "chatCode": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The chat code of the inTest alliance. Used to identify inTest alliance's chat room.",
      "required": true
    },
    "members":{
      "type": "object",
      "description": "The members of the inTest alliance. The key is the player id of the member.",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "$ref": "./ClientInTestAllianceMember.json"
      },
      "required": true,
      "existingJavaType": "java.util.Map<Integer, ClientInTestAllianceMember>"
    },
    "logMessages":{
      "type": "array",
      "description": "The messages about important events in the inTest alliance, e.g. leader change, member leave, etc. The newest messages are at the end of the list.",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "./ClientInTestAllianceLogMessage.json"
      }
    },
    "applicants":{
      "type": "array",
      "description": "The applicants of the inTest alliance.",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "./ClientInTestAllianceApplicant.json"
      }
    },
    "invitations":{
      "type": "array",
      "description": "The invitations to the inTest alliance.",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "./ClientInTestAllianceInvitation.json"
      }
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

ClientInTestAllianceApplicant.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "ClientInTestAllianceApplicant",
  "description": "Representation of an inTest alliance applicant",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "@c": {
      "type": "string",
      "const": "ultshared.UltInTestAllianceApplicant",
      "description": "The class describing the json object",
      "required": true,
      "javaName": "jsonTypeId"
    },
    "playerID": {
      "type": "integer",
      "description": "The player ID of the applicant",
      "required": true
    },
    "timeStamp": {
      "type": "integer",
      "description": "The timestamp when application was made (in milliseconds since epoch)",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

ClientInTestAllianceInvitation.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "ClientInTestAllianceInvitation",
  "description": "Representation of an alliance invitation",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "@c": {
      "type": "string",
      "const": "ultshared.FrontendInTestAllianceInvitation",
      "description": "The class describing the json object",
      "required": true,
      "javaName": "jsonTypeId"
    },
    "invitingPlayerID": {
      "type": "integer",
      "descrition": "The ID of the player who sent the invitation",
      "required": true
    },
    "invitedPlayerID": {
      "type": "integer",
      "description": "The ID of the player who received the invitation",
      "required": true
    },
    "timeStamp": {
      "type": "integer",
      "description": "The time at which the invitation was sent (in milliseconds since epoch)",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

ClientInTestAllianceLogMessage.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "ClientInTestAllianceLogMessage",
  "description": "Representation of a log message about an alliance action",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "@c": {
      "type": "string",
      "const": "ultshared.UltInTestAllianceLogMessage",
      "description": "The class describing the json object",
      "required": true,
      "javaName": "jsonTypeId"
    },
    "logDate": {
      "type": "integer",
      "description": "Server time when the action was created (in milliseconds since epoch)",
      "required": true
    },
    "playerID": {
      "type": "integer",
      "description": "The player who did the action",
      "required": true
    },
    "targetPlayerID": {
      "type": "integer",
      "description": "The player who was the target of the action. Could be zero if a player left the alliance by himself",
      "required": true
    },
    "inTestAllianceAction": {
      "type": "integer",
      "description": "The type of action. See the server class UltInTestAllianceAction to know the possible values",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

ClientInTestAllianceMember.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "ClientInTestAllianceMember",
  "description": "Represents a member of an alliance",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "@c": {
      "type": "string",
      "const": "ultshared.UltInTestAllianceMember",
      "description": "The class describing the json object",
      "required": true,
      "javaName": "jsonTypeId"
    },
    "playerID": {
      "type": "integer",
      "descrition": "The player ID of the member",
      "required": true
    },
    "joinDate": {
      "type": "integer",
      "description": "The date the member joined the alliance",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

and i want output like this

unified_client_json_schema.json

```
   {
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "definitions": {
    "UltInGameAlliance": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "@c": {
          "type": "string",
          "const": "ultshared.UltInGameAlliance",
          "description": "The class describing the json object",
          "required": true,
          "javaName": "jsonTypeId"
        },
        "allianceID": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "The id of the in-game alliance",
          "required": true
        },
        "leaderID": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "The player id of the leader of the in-game alliance",
          "required": true
        },
        "chatCode": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The chat code of the in-game alliance. Used to identify in-game alliance's chat room.",
          "required": true
        },
        "members": {
          "type": "object",
          "description": "The members of the in-game alliance. The key is the player id of the member.",
          "additionalProperties": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/ClientInGameAllianceMember"
          },
          "required": true,
          "existingJavaType": "java.util.Map<Integer, ClientInGameAllianceMember>"
        },
        "logMessages": {
          "type": "array",
          "description": "The messages about important events in the in-game alliance, e.g., leader change, member leave, etc. The newest messages are at the end of the list.",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/ClientInGameAllianceLogMessage"
          }
        },
        "applicants": {
          "type": "array",
          "description": "The applicants of the in-game alliance.",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/ClientInGameAllianceApplicant"
          }
        },
        "invitations": {
          "type": "array",
          "description": "The invitations to the in-game alliance.",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/ClientInGameAllianceInvitation"
          }
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "ClientInGameAllianceApplicant": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "@c": {
          "type": "string",
          "const": "ultshared.UltInGameAllianceApplicant",
          "description": "The class describing the json object",
          "required": true,
          "javaName": "jsonTypeId"
        },
        "playerID": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "The player ID of the applicant",
          "required": true
        },
        "timeStamp": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "The timestamp when the application was made (in milliseconds since epoch)",
          "required": true
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "ClientInGameAllianceInvitation": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "@c": {
          "type": "string",
          "const": "ultshared.FrontendInGameAllianceInvitation",
          "description": "The class describing the json object",
          "required": true,
          "javaName": "jsonTypeId"
        },
        "invitingPlayerID": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "The ID of the player who sent the invitation",
          "required": true
        },
        "invitedPlayerID": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "The ID of the player who received the invitation",
          "required": true
        },
        "timeStamp": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "The time at which the invitation was sent (in milliseconds since epoch)",
          "required": true
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "ClientInGameAllianceLogMessage": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "@c": {
          "type": "string",
          "const": "ultshared.UltInGameAllianceLogMessage",
          "description": "The class describing the json object",
          "required": true,
          "javaName": "jsonTypeId"
        },
        "logDate": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "Server time when the action was created (in milliseconds since epoch)",
          "required": true
        },
        "playerID": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "The player who did the action",
          "required": true
        },
        "targetPlayerID": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "The player who was the target of the action. Could be zero if a player left the alliance by himself",
          "required": true
        },
        "inGameAllianceAction": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "The type of action. See the server class UltInGameAllianceAction to know the possible values",
          "required": true
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "ClientInGameAllianceMember": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "@c": {
          "type": "string",
          "const": "ultshared.UltInGameAllianceMember",
          "description": "The class describing the json object",
          "required": true,
          "javaName": "jsonTypeId"
        },
        "playerID": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "The player ID of the member",
          "required": true
        },
        "joinDate": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "The date the member joined the alliance",
          "required": true
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your purpose of merging them?

Comment: there are use cases where this separation is not helpful. For example an OpenAPI specification requires these schemas to be merged into one. Also code generators like quicktype require a unified schema file.

Comment: OpenAPI welcomes the use of references, it doesn't require a merged schema. Code generators are dependent on the JSON Schema implementation they use, which again, if done correctly, can dereference most any schema. The JSON Schema 2020-12 specification defines bundling https://apisyouwonthate.com/blog/json-schema-bundling-finally-formalised/

Comment: This is my client requirements, they have multiple jsons file and they can not upload each files in OpenAPI that's why they want code to merge all jsons into one

Comment: merging all schemas into one can be very difficult or impossible, depending on how they structure their schemas. It can also change the behavior if the tooling used is not careful with the ref resolution

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the OpenAPI description as the entry point, [Redocly](https://redocly.com/docs/cli/commands/bundle/) can easily handle this request with their Bundle cli command.

`redocly bundle --dereference <openapi.json> --output <path/to/output> --ext json`